# Delete data from elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to delete data of particular type from Elasticsearch. I am using the Sense plugin within Chrome to execute my delete command. When I execute the command to delete index, it works for id, but not for type. In Sense I used:

- `DELETE /index`

  - It deleted all data for that index.
- `DELETE /index/type/id`

  - It delete data of that id.
- `DELETE /index/type`

  - gives error of No handler.

Than I also tried curl commands via Cygwin to do same task it was not working, but it gave me a message about unknown curl. Please help me to know how to delete data of particular type.

Comment: Richa is offering the right solution. As a side note, Cygwin does not install `curl` by default, so you need to install it before it will work. The reason that `DELETE /index/type` exclaims that there is "No handler" is because the delete API only expects `{index}/{type}/{id}` **or** `{index}` as of ES 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are using Elasticsearch version 2.x.
In ES 2.x it is not allowed delete a particular type. See [this](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking_20_mapping_changes.html#_types_may_no_longer_be_deleted).

You can use [delete by query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/plugins-delete-by-query.html) to delete a particular type.

Install `delete-by-query` plugin using

```
sudo bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

And then run

```
DELETE /index/type/_query
```

This would delete the documents of that particular type.

Comment: You can use the delete by query plugin to _effectively_ delete a particular type. Note that its mappings will survive the operation.

Comment: You should show the example in your answer incase the links break. (I didn't downvote because those links should survive for awhile, but the breaking changes link will definitely break eventually due to `current` being in it)

Comment: @pickypg.Thnx for your comment. The answer is delete by query plugin and I have added that in my answer. So what else should be added in it? Please explain..

Comment: Literally show the example of how to install it and how to then use it: `bin/plugin install delete-by-query` and `DELETE /index/type/_query`

Comment: @pickypg: Thnx for telling me the improvement. Edited my answer

Comment: Hi,Richa thanks for help.Actually I am new for elasticsearch and unable to install delete-by-query plugin even after follow that document which u had shared.Can u pls tell step by step to do that thing.I will be grateful if u share those steps. Thanks....